# How should I solve the following simultaneous equations?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, estimators, pareto-distribution, optimization

I have the set of simultaneous equations below from the paper *Parameter estimation for 3-parameter generalized pareto distribution by the principle of maximum entropy (POME)* by VP Singh and H Guo:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_i - c)/\hat{b}}{1-\hat{a}(x_i-c)/\hat{b}} = \frac{n}{1-\hat{a}}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} ln[1-\hat{a}(x_i-c)/\hat{b}] = -n\hat{a}
$$

In this problem $c$ is set by me. $x$ is a vector of returns $\geq c$ and $n$ is the number of elements in $x$. Does anyone have any recommendations for how to solve for $a$ and $b$? I generally use bisection as my go to root solver but 
I have never used it to find two variables.

For what it's worth I am programming in C++ per my advisor's request but that is the next question.

Comment: On an answer to an earlier question of yours [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179455/have-mle-estimators-for-generalized-pareto-distribution-given-a-known-value-of) I gave the quite explicit advice to minimize the negative log-likelihood by *directly solving the minimization problem* using standard tools, rather than taking the step in the paper you point to of taking derivatives and then trying to make it a root-finding problem (which they give no advice on). Since you're fairly likely to get the same advice again, you should explain why you don't do it.

Comment: I spent the weekend working on the minimization problem you reference however I couldn't find standard tools that both worked well with visual studio and minimization problems with a vector in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On thinking about this for a bit, I think I see how to solve this problem  directly without any need for iteration.

I'll refer to the Wikipedia pages for the [Generalized Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution) and the [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution). You'll now need to navigate between three sets of notation, but the critical one is $a=\xi=1/\alpha$. Note also that in the discussion below $x_{(1)}$ means the first order statistic (the smallest observation).

(Note added much later: here I seem to be assuming $a>0$.)

1. Given $c$ and assuming we have some suitable $\hat{b}$, let $z_i = \frac{x_i-c}{\hat{b}}$ (you'll need these to be such that all the $x_i>c$ and all the $z_i>1$). You now have a [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution#Definition) generalized Pareto, which has only one parameter:

   $f_a(z) = (az+1)^{-\frac{a+1}{a}} $

   You could of course try univariate optimization on this new problem, but there's a direct solution.

   Use the connection between the Pareto and the Generalized Pareto to solve for $\hat{a}$. Note that in the equivalent Pareto, $x_m=1$. In fact we can even take logs just and solve for the exponential scale parameter. Either way this gives that $\hat{a}$ is the mean of the $\log(z_i)$.

   So any time we have an estimate of $\hat{b}$ we can immediately get the corresponding ML estimate $\hat{a}$ using step 1.
2. This leaves us with "how to estimate $b$". Note that given $c$, the discussion for estimating $x_m$ under the Pareto would lead us to set $\hat{b}=\min(x_i-c)=\min(x_i)-c=x_{(1)}-c$.

   (This precludes the case where we estimate $c$ by setting $\hat{c}=\min(x_i)$ unless we then remove that observation from further participation, but I don't think you'll have that issue. I discuss at the end how to deal with that, though.)

   The same thing is used when estimating location and scale for a shifted exponential; set location to the minimum observation and then use the remaining observations to estimate the scale parameter.

   Note that this doesn't satisfy $z_i>1$ for the observation we just used (but does for all the others). We actually need the same trick we were just discussing, except this time it's *exactly* the shifted exponential issue; we eliminate the observation that gives $\hat{b}$, i.e. set $\hat{b}=x_{(1)}-c$
   and lose that observation when estimating $a$.

---

If you estimate both $b$ and $c$ from the data you will lose the smallest two observations, the first in obtaining $c$ ($\hat{c}=x_{(1)}$) and the second obtaining $b$ ($\hat{b}=x_{(2)}-\hat{c}=x_{(2)}-x_{(1)}$), and then estimate $a$ as the mean of the logs of the remaining $z_i$.

Comment: I will first attempt to execute the minimization problem using the partials first then if necessary look at what you just wrote. I think trying to force my problem into open source libraries like GSL, dlib and nlopt. Thanks.

Comment: What I have there should maximize the likelihood; one difficulty for the usual iterative methods is that the the ML estimate for $b$ is at a boundary (but as long as you deal with any attempt by the minimizer to cross that boundary it should still work; note that $-\log \mathcal{L}$ will go to infinity there). However, I'm not sure why you'd need to, since the two steps I outline above will be very fast and should result in what you need (you can always check by evaluating the likelihood function in a plausible region near it - something that is good practice in any case).

Comment: Excellent I will look at this. Thanks for your help.